# gcc -lm doesn't fix undefined reference to `atan'

Tags: linux, math, gcc, linker

Eclipse 3.8.1 Linux Mint

Added -lm to Project / C/C++ Build / Settings / GCC C Linker / Command:

```
gcc -lm
```

Console messages:

```
Building target: Nicomedes
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -lm  -o "Nicomedes"  ./Nicomedes.o   
./Nicomedes.o: In function `main':
/home/bogwan/work/Nicomedes/Debug/../Nicomedes.c:244: undefined reference to `pow'
/home/bogwan/work/Nicomedes/Debug/../Nicomedes.c:258: undefined reference to `atan'
/home/bogwan/work/Nicomedes/Debug/../Nicomedes.c:260: undefined reference to `atan'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Nicomedes] Error 1

07:29:58 Build Finished (took 108ms)
```

Comment: Your linkage order is wrong. Make it `gcc -o "Nicomedes"  ./Nicomedes.o -lm`. In the linkage sequence, files that need symbol definitions must come before the ones that provide the definitions. So libraries after object files.

Comment: @MikeKinghan: Not sure why you posted that as a comment. It's the correct answer, and thus deserves upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your linkage order is wrong. Make it gcc -o "Nicomedes" ./Nicomedes.o -lm. 
In the linkage sequence, files that need symbol definitions must come before 
the ones that provide the definitions. So libraries after object files.

In Eclipse, the setting **C/C++ Build** -> **Settings** -> **GCC C Linker** -> **Command**
is intended to set the program that you want to do your linking, not your linkage
options. Set library options in **C/C++ Build** -> **Settings** -> **GCC C Linker** -> **Libraries**